# Group by multiple column acquired from join

Tags: mysql, group-by

this is part of a query result :

[image]

all three columns are `user_id`s acquired from multiple tables join .
as you see **each row has only one user_id and two other user_ids are necessarily `null`** .
I'm going to group this rows by `user_id` regardless of the column it is on.

so i need to have all user_ids in one column (instead of three) to make me enable to perform `group by` on it. the ultimate result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). If *table1.user_id* is null then it will use *table2.user_id*. If that is null then it uses *table3.user_id* and so on.

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1.user_id, table2.user_id, table3.user_id) AS `xx_user_id`
FROM ...table joins...
GROUP BY `xx_user_id`
```

You won't be able to use the derived `xx_user_id` column in a `WHERE` clause however you can use it in a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1.user_id, table2.user_id, table3.user_id) AS `xx_user_id`
FROM ...table joins...
GROUP BY `xx_user_id`
HAVING `xx_user_id` = 123;
```

Comment: excellent . and this is the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to MYSQL `COALESCE` documentation